# How to attach function to events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
    // param {name:'name', click : function(ev[,arg1, arg2] ){}, focus:function(ev[,arg1, arg2] ){} }
    ToggleButton = function(params) {
         var btn = document.getElementId(params.name);
         // how to hook the above click function passed using 
         // params and pass additional params along with it like function(ev[,arg1,arg2]) 
         btn.onclick = params.click;
    }
```

I am trying to implement extended link button to act like a toggle button. Now I would like to be able to  attach event as specified above but I am not getting it how to attach it to the buttons so that I can enjoy code like below?

```
new ToggleButton({name: 'toggle1', "click" :  function(evt, obj1, obj1){ 
        //function body 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it that way:

```
<a href="foo.html" id="toggle1">Toogle</a>


var ToggleButton = function(params) {
    var btn  = document.getElementById(params.id);
    var evt  = 'on' + params.evt;
    btn[evt] = params.action;    
    return;
}

ToggleButton({
    id:      'toggle1',
    evt:     'click',
    action:  function(evt){
        var clickedElement = this;
        alert('My href is '+ clickedElement.getAttribute('href'));

        // Prevent the browser from following the href, 
        // just in case you set this attribute
        var e = evt || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: How should i pass more parameters to event function ? is that possible ?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: The example u have show is fine this is exactly what i wanted. But additional thing i am trying is to pass the object to event in addition to the evt. So that i dont have to use public variables or need to rely on closures.

Comment: if you mean the clicked element, you can acces it with "this" inside the function. Have a look at my post, I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
ToggleButton = function( params) {
      var button = document.getElementById( params.name);
      if ( button) {
         button.onclick = params.click;
      }
}
```